# Getting ValueError: The estimator Sequential should be a regressor when creating a Stacking ensemble using LSTM and GRU

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lstm, ensemble-learning

I am a beginner in Machine Learning and trying to create a Stacking Ensemble algorithm using LSTM and GRU. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "I:\API and Dataset\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_stacking.py", line 684, in fit
    return super().fit(X, y, sample_weight)
  File "I:\API and Dataset\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_stacking.py", line 139, in fit
    names, all_estimators = self._validate_estimators()
  File "I:\API and Dataset\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_base.py", line 241, in _validate_estimators
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The estimator Sequential should be a regressor
```

I am not sure how to interpret this error or what to make of it. Below are my models for reference.

**LSTM Model**

```
# model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(1,3), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
LSTMmodel.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, input_shape=(1, lookback))))
LSTMmodel.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
LSTMmodel.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
LSTMmodel.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
LSTMmodel.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
keras.backend.set_value(LSTMmodel.optimizer.learning_rate, 0.0007)
LSTMmodel.fit(X_train, Y_train_scaled, epochs=10, batch_size=5000, verbose=1)
```

*Note: The GRU model structure is similar to LSTM*

**Stacking Ensemble Model**

```
estimator_list = [('GRUmodel', GRUmodel), ('LSTMmodel', LSTMmodel)]
stack_model = StackingRegressor(estimators=estimator_list, final_estimator=LogisticRegression)
stack_model.fit(X_train, Y_train.ravel())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using StackingRegressor whereas your final_estimator is a classifer. You can try using StackingClassifier if you intend to use LogisticRegression as your final_estimator.

Comment: I tried using StackingClassifier just now and it gave me a value error which essentially means that I am passing floats into a classifier. This is a regression problem and not a classification problem. Any other clue?

Comment: If its a regression problem then why are you using "LogisticRegression" as final_estimator because "LogisticRegression" is a classifier.

Comment: Try using some other regressor as your final_estimator

Comment: Can you advise which one to use please? I am a newbie. I tried using LinearRegression but didn't work.

Comment: What's the error that u got when using LinearRegression ?